# OpenLayers 7 WFS 1.1.0 not drawing polygons when srsName contains opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, javascript, wfs, proj

I'm writing a web app that uses WFS data on top of OpenLayers with OpenStreetMap. The entire project works in EPSG:2180 projection and uses multiple versions of WFS (depending on server). OL doesn't draw polygons on the map when srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180" instead of srsName="EPSG:2180".

I tried adding EquivalentProjections as in documentation and it even returns true on check. However, still, no geometries are drawn.

Code:

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import * as ol_proj4 from 'ol/proj/proj4.js';
import * as olProj from 'ol/proj';

[...]

proj4.defs("EPSG:2180","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs +axis=neu");
ol_proj4.register(proj4);

var epsg_nazwa_xml = new olProj.Projection ({
  code: 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180',
  units: 'm',
  axisOrientation: 'neu',
  global: false,
  metersPerUnit: 1,
}) 
olProj.addProjection(epsg_nazwa_xml);

olProj.addEquivalentProjections([epsg_nazwa_xml, olProj.get('EPSG:2180')]);

console.log(olProj.equivalent(olProj.get('EPSG:2180'), olProj.get('http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180')))

[...]

/**
 * MAPA init
 */
var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
      projection: 'EPSG:2180'
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:2180',
    center: miejsce,
    zoom: 14,
  })
});

[...]

WFSvectorSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new WFS({
          version: '1.1.0',
        }),
        url: function(extent) {
            return compURL+"&bbox="+extent.join(',')+",EPSG:2180";
        },
        strategy: bbox
      });
WFSvectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: WFSvectorSource,
      projection: 'EPSG:2180',

      style: new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
              color: '#000000',
              width: 1
          }),
          fill: new Fill({
              color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01)'
          })
      }),
    });
map.addLayer(WFSvectorLayer);
```

Example of working WFS link:
https://corsproxy.io/?https://trzebnicki-wms.webewid.pl/iip/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki&bbox=357783.463892855,391038.4860643449,358805.47125767067,391700.3901630342

and not working WFS link:
https://corsproxy.io/?https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki&bbox=332468.6208316547,272386.1313619815,333179.64381146623,272819.1873043835

The only difference being in only in srsName in <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:2180"> vs <gml:Polygon srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180">

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The `trzebnicki-wms.webewid.pl` service GetCapabilities suggests you should be using the `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180` form to reference the SRS, vs the `geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl` servers `EPSG:2180` form.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't make a difference. I still think that it is the matter of making 'EPSG:2180' and 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180' equal to the XMLparser, but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: Your https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp? example request doesn't return any data for me, but a request without that bounding box does with EPSG:2180, (https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki&maxfeatures=100).  Both servers return the expected ` text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1` output format.  So it looks like a BBOX issue

Comment: GML will work but the assumption that `EPSG:2180` and `http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180` are equivalent is not correct.  Only EPSG:2180 uses axis order neu, so they must be defined as separate projections https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-qpk1dr?file=/main.js

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much Mike, this is what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the BBOX.  The BBOX should include the `crsuri` unless the coordinates are specified in WGS 84 decimal degrees (according to the WFS 1.1.0 specification).

So the request should be:

```
https://corsproxy.io/?https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki&bbox=332468.6208316547,272386.1313619815,333179.64381146623,272819.1873043835,EPSG:2180
```

So the working WFS example using MapServer software is non-compliant to the standard (or lax) whereas the non-working example is conforming to the standard and not returning data.

Answer (score 0):

I played with a little with `outputFormat` and managed to show both layers with  `EPSG:2180` projection. Since there is a huge number of features, I limited returned number with the `maxFeatures` parameter.

For the first URL `https://corsproxy.io/?https://trzebnicki-wms.webewid.pl/iip/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki` I left default output format, which is GML 3.1.1.

This is the complete code:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2180","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs +axis=neu");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

function url(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
  var url = 'https://corsproxy.io/?https://trzebnicki-wms.webewid.pl/iip/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki' 
            + '&maxFeatures=5000&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:2180';
  return url;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GML(),
  url: url,
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});


var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:2180',
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([17.059, 51.36], 'EPSG:2180'),
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 11
  })
});
```

And this is the result of the above code:

[image]

For the second URL  `https://corsproxy.io/?https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki` I couldn't make it work with GML output format, so I took simpler GeoJSON.

This is the complete code:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2180","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs +axis=neu");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

function url(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
  var url = 'https://corsproxy.io/?https://geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl/ggp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsname=EPSG:2180&typename=dzialki' 
            + '&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=json&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:2180';
  return url;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataFormat: 'EPSG:2180', featureFormat: 'EPSG:2180'}),
  url: url,
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});


var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:2180',
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([16.649, 50.6], 'EPSG:2180'),
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 13
  })
});
```

And this is the result of the above code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using over 300 different WFS servers in this project and GML3 is the only format that all of them support.  Your way works, but I have to use gml. Is there a way to do it? I think GML3 doesnt render because geoportal.powiat.klodzko.pl returns srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2180" instead of srsName="EPSG:2180" . Is it possible to make it work? Thanks